# Show multiple content in a view in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content-type named **Accessories**. Where I can create content related product i.e. Product name, product detail, etc. I have a view named **shop** where I can display all products of the content-type i.e. **Accessories**.

Now I want to create a view where I can show the product detail. I can't find-out how to do this.

Please help to create Views to show my product details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you have to create second view of type page i.e. `product_detail` & add path to them i.e. `product_datail/%`.
2. Inside your first view `Content : Title` add **Rewrite Result**

   - **Check** : Output this field as a link
   - **Link Path** : `product_detail/[title]`
   - **Check** : Use absolute path
3. In both your first & second view i.e. **shop** & **product_detail**

Add Contexual Filter i.e. `Content: Title`

Save that view & run. I hope your issue will solved.

Comment: Ok will try & confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The "content related product i.e. Product name, product detail*" in your question is a bit ambiguous ... (not sure how to correctly interprete) ...

**1st possibility**:

It may mean that you only have a single content-type (named "Accessories") with some fields added to it, i.e. product name, product detail, product image, etc.

In that case, you should the "add" button to the right of Views "Fields" (1st column of the Views UI). First to add a field like Product name, and then for product detail, product image, etc.

**2nd possibility**:

It may mean that you have a content type "Accessories", and another type like "Product" or something.

In that case, you should add a Views "Relationships" (3rd column of the Views UI).

Comment: I have only a content-type named "Accessories" where are some fields i.e. product name, product detail, product image, etc.

Comment: Thx for clarifying that, let me re-edit my answer ...

Comment: Ok. Have you understand what I want to ask. Please help me I am new in drupal.